# Skylander Swap Force Woodborrow pool

Tags: skylanders-swap-force

How do you jump into the the pool in Woodborrow? Do you have to complete any certain level or have a certain character or characters?

Answer (score 1):

To jump into the pool in Woodburrow, you need to first get past the 3rd level, Mudwater Hollow. Once you're past that section of the game, go left and up from the main area and look for mushrooms sticking out from the left side of the tree. Climb all the way to the top, past a Soul Gem, Winged Sapphire & some fireworks you should see a Magic Circle that'll launch you all the way into the pool.

Comment: What gaming system are you using? The Wii doesn't have a magic circle passed the fireworks. What character did you use?

Comment: I've played on the PS3. The circle doesn't appear until you've gotten past the 3rd level, are you past that point in the game? Did you get rid of the fireworks with a Fire Skylander?

Comment: How long do you have to fire off the fireworks before the circle appears? Yes, we are well past the 3rd level.

Comment: Until they disappear, I believe. You have to fire at them with a fire Skylander a few times until they do (there's a PS3 Trophy/X360 Achievement attached to that)